# How can I fix a vertical section?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to divide my screen in two vertical areas, where the left one should not scroll.

```
+--------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                |                 |
|                                |   Fixed,        |
|                                |   No scrolling  |
|        Regular behavior        |                 |
|                                |                 |
|                                |                 |
|                                |                 |
|                                |                 |
|                                |                 |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

How can I achieve this with Bootstrap3? as I would like to the styling and forms from Bootstrap.

Note:
Responsive design is not needed, as this will only be seen by desktops.
I know that Bootstrap3 might be overkill for this. I just need this layout and some styling for a form and few buttons. I just find Bootstrap quite well documented and popular.

Super thanks!

Comment: You need to have a container div and two divs inside it. Give fixed height to DIV on right & you are done.

Comment: _“Super thanks!”_ – yeah, right. But you forgot to give us your billing address …

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers below. They all work for plain CSS, but how to do it for Bootsrap3?

Comment: Maybe I could have these containers without Bootstrap3, and still have the form inside with Bootstrap. I'll test it tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some thing like that ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/VfTYs/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="myleft">
        <h1>I'm on the left !</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="myright">
        I'm fixed on the right !
        <ul>
            <li>some</li>
            <li>items</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<h1>Other thing ...</h1>
```

CSS:

```
    html
{
    background-color  : #111111;
    color             : #DDDDDD;
}

body
{
    padding           : 0;
    margin            : 0;
}

#container
{
    height             : 1500px;    
}

#container>.myleft
{
    background-color  : #444444;
    width             : 100%;
    height            : 100%;
    float             : left;
}

#container>.myright
{
    background-color : #222222;
    position         : fixed;
    right            : 0;
    height           : 100%;
}
```

Comment: I put my Bootstrap container-div inside "myright" and then I can use its form controls. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Style is,

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.left{
  float:left;
  width:70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using DIVs.But you need to specify the width and other necessary attributes.To meet your main requirements,the right Div should be set to fixed and non-scrolling.More details in codes below:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div class="left" style="width:70%;float:left"></div>
    <div class="right" style="width:30%;position:fixed;overflow:hidden;float:right"></div></div>
```

And the height can be default as the field may fill the whole screen.

The css codes should be added to a CSS FILE.I write it in HTML just for illustration purposes.